# split URL using Regular Expression in IIS

Tags: regex, url, iis, url-rewriting

I am facing challenges in splitting the URL using regular expression.

I want to change the mid of the URL part since we changed the URL of the site pages.

```
      https://test.company.com/about/news/2015/test/award.aspx
```

The above given URL needs to replace as below,

```
      https://test.company.com/en/about/media/news/2015/test/award.aspx
```

I want to achieve this functionality using Regular Expression in IIS.

I tried the code as below in **URL Rewrite** in **IIS**,

```
      about/news/2015(.*.+?)
```

Help to resolve this as required, thanks in advance.

Comment: I have never used IIS, however I do know regex.  Can you just split it into multiple capturing groups?  Something like `(^.*\.com/)(about/)(.*$)` and then replace it with something like `$1en/$2media/$3`?  Syntax might be slightly different in IIS.

Comment: Does [this](https://regex101.com/r/ZmWQTh/1) help?

Answer (score 0):

The regex engine gets the string without the host and protocol, starting with `about`. Thus, you need to match starting with this fixed string, capture the parts between which you need to insert the required value and use

```
^(about)(/news/2015/)
```

Replace with

```
en/{R:1}/media{R:2}
```

Where `{R:1}` refers to `about` and the `{R:2}` refers to `/news/2015/`.

Here is a [demo of how this regex works](https://regex101.com/r/1TkMbs/1).

Answer (score 0):

You could try below rule:

```
 <rule name="rule11-1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^about/news/2015/(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/about/(.*)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://test.company.com/en/about/media/{C:1}" />
            </rule>
```

[image]